# Using global map variable with BaseX collection

Tags: xml, xquery, basex, xquery-3.0

I'm using BaseX (v9.3.2) XQuery v3.1. I have a XQuery script that evaluates all XML files in a BaseX collection. The collection has about 100 files, each one with a size between 30MB to 1.5GB and with the same XSD schema. The script for better performance uses the BaseX [Map Module](https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Map_Module) for mapping keys to values and get values quickly by key. I have declared several module-global variables of type `map(*)`. The crux is that the key values are only unique in *one* XML file. In order to make the key unique over the whole collection i've simply added `base-uri($value),'_'` as an additional part of the key :). It works fine. The main drawback i see, is the need of *tunneling* the `base-uri` through all consecutive function calls `FooN($baseuri, $arg2) FooN-1($baseuri, $arg2) ... Foo1($baseuri, $arg2)` even if the `$baseuri` value is set with the first call `FooN($baseuri, $arg2)` but used only in the last function of the execution chain. To make it more clear see the XQuery Code below. Here the `$basuri` is lastly only needed in `helper:Foo1` but we need to pass it as an argument in `helper:Foo2` too.

My question is if there is a better approach with respect to the arguments tunneling and with no other drawbacks (performance, memory).

### XQuery Code

```
xquery version "3.1" encoding "utf-8";

declare namespace helper="helperns";

declare variable $helper:root := db:open("BMW");

declare variable $helper:mapAS_ApplicationRecordElementByTypeRef as map(*) := map:merge(for $value in $helper:root//*:APPLICATION-RECORD-ELEMENT[*:TYPE-TREF/@DEST='APPLICATION-PRIMITIVE-DATA-TYPE'] return map:entry(concat(base-uri($value),'_',$value/*:TYPE-TREF/tokenize(text(),'/')[last()]), $value));
declare variable $helper:mapAS_ImplementationDataTypeRefByApplicationDatatypeRef as map(*) := ...


...

declare function helper:Foo1($applPrimitiveDataType as element(),$basuri as xs:string)
as element() {
  let $applRecordElement := map:get($helper:mapAS_ApplicationRecordElementByTypeRef, concat($basuri,'_',$applPrimitiveDataType/*:SHORT-NAME/text()))
...
  let $resolved := if($implDataTypeElement) then (
...
    )
    else (
      <RESOLVED_DATATYPE>
        <SHORT-NAME resolveinfo='not resolved (DB ERROR)'>unknown</SHORT-NAME>
      </RESOLVED_DATATYPE>  
    )
  return ($resolved)
};

...

declare function helper:Foo2($basuri as xs:string)
as element()* {
  let $applicationPrimitiveDataTypes := ...
  let $res :=
    for $applicationPrimitiveDataType in $applicationPrimitiveDataTypes
...
      order by $shortname
      return (
        if (not($implDataTypeRef)) then (
          let $dataTypeResolved := helper:Foo1($applicationPrimitiveDataType,$basuri)
          return(
            <MAPPING appldtname="{$shortname}" size="{$dataTypeResolved/*:SHORT-NAME/@size}" basedatatype="{$dataTypeResolved/*:SHORT-NAME}" resolveinfo="{$dataTypeResolved/SHORT-NAME/@resolveinfo}"/>
          )
        )
      )
  return($res)
};


let $mappingsForAllDocs :=
  for $doc in helper:getAllDocs()/doc
...
    let $missingmappings := helper:Foo2($doc/@baseuri)
    return (
      <FILE name="{$doc/@filename}" missing="{count($missingmappings)}">
        <MISSING-MAPPING>{$missingmappings}</MISSING-MAPPING>
...
      </FILE>
    )

let $allDocs :=
  for $doc in helper:getAllDocs()/doc
    order by $doc/@filename
    return (
      <FILE name="{$doc/@filename}"/>
    )

return($mappingsForAllDocs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered updating the XML files (or generating a new set) with unique IDs? Once there are unique IDs, XML databases like BaseX are capable of fast lookups using the `fn:id()` function. For updating XML files, see https://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update.

Comment: thank you, it looks like a good practical approach, i'll explore it. I hoped there was syntactical support in XQuery similar to the tunnel feature with parameters in XSLT v2.

Comment: I have updated the collection and made the respective `/path//to/the/@ID` unique:  `for $id in /path//to/the/@ID return replace value of node $id with concat(base-uri($id),'_',$id)`. Undo works fine too: `for $id in /path//to/the/@ID return replace value of node $id with replace($id,concat(base-uri($id),"_"),'')`.